# When I import an OBJ it won't show up, does anybody know how to fix it?

Tags: objects, import

When I try to import wavefront .obj, it won't show up. It appears in the explorer, but I can't see it when I try to edit. Does anybody know how to solve this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me at times, .obj files have imported super huge or super small. It might still be there but out of view. Try selecting it in outliner window in upper right and then in the 3D window hit <kbd>.</kbd> on your numpad or choose *View > Selection* in *Object Mode*.